# Function to set this.state.isLoading to false doesn't work inside navigationOptions

Tags: react-native

I am setting isLoading: false inside `this.state=` but it doesn't work. Nothing sets to false or true

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;

    if (navigation.state.params instanceof Object) {
      console.log("OBJECT");
      if (typeof params.usernameValue !== "undefined") {
        console.log("FALSE");

        );
        navigation.state.params.changeLoadingState(false);
      } else {
        console.log("TRUE");
        navigation.state.params.changeLoadingState(true);
      }
    }
}
```

And the rest

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    const changeLoadingState = isLoadingState =>
      this.setState({ isLoadingState });

    const isLoadingState = this.state.isLoading;

    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      isLoadingState: false,
      changeLoadingState
    });
}
```

The console log shows FALSE so it goes inside the IF statement but it doesn't change the loadingState to false. Like the changeLoadingState doesn't work. The output of the navigation.state.params = {"isLoadingState":false}.

Why doesn't my isLoading state change to false? Please help me someone, i would really aprreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting state like this?

```
this.setState({ isLoading: isLoadingState });
```

Comment: Worked perfeclty, thanks for your time to write this. Have a nice day!